# how to show error in jquery after clicking submit button

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

My problem is that after clicking on submit button the page will go to php file any way my html code is like this

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><div id="adiv"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
</form>
```

and my jquery code goes like this

```
$('#name').focusout(function(){
    if($('#name').val().length==0){ 
        $('#adiv').html("please enter name")
    }
});
$('#button').click(function(){
    if($('#name').val().length==0){
        $('#adiv').html("please enter your name")
    }
});
```

but after clicking submit button it redirects to php file and doesn't show any error and store blank data in the database.

Comment: You can do validation with Javascript, but you should always validate the input on the server-side as well. (With PHP in your case.) People can simple disable Javascript and still send invalid data.

Answer (score 3):

Because your `input type is submit` you can either `change the type to button` or add `event.preventDefault()` to avoid automatic passing of form

use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();//this will stop form auto submit thus showing your error
    if ($('#name').val().length == 0) {
        $('#adiv').html("please enter your name")
    }
});
```

Or

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
```

change to

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="button">//also prevent form auto submit thus will show the error
```

Comment: Please use the submit event instead of the click event

Comment: @mplungjan im just showing the use of `e.preventDefault()` that is why i used click.

Comment: See my answer for the user of submit instead

Comment: I do not recommend using the click handler of a button to validate the form. Instead use the submit handler of the form. It is what it is there for. Also put the preventDefault where the error is if you want the form to submit at all

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to stop the code to execute after error has been detected. For example you can simple use `return false` or `return`:

```js
$('#name').focusout(function() {
  if ($('#name').val().length == 0) {
    $('#adiv').html("please enter name")
  }
});
$('#button').click(function() {
  if ($('#name').val().length == 0) {
    $('#adiv').html("please enter your name")
    return false;//add this
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <div id="adiv"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('your-form').on('submit', function(e) { 
e.preventDefault(); 
//your code bere
});
```

preventDefault stop the normal submit behaviour of your browser so that you can trigger any event you want

Comment: Then the form will never submit unless we submit it again in the code, then what is the use of a submit button

Comment: Inside your code you check of there is any error. If yes, you don't have to submit and just show the error. If no, you can send ajax request or trigger the submit again like this: $('your-form').submit()..... Or do whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

try this..:D

```js
function validateFunction(){
    if(document.getElementByID('name').value.length==0){
        document.getElementByID('adiv').innerHTML = "please enter your name";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="button" onclick="return validateFunction();" />
```

Comment: 1: do not add inline event handlers - especially not if you have jQuery. 2: do not assign validations to a submit button

Comment: won't this code work??
can i get a specific reason for this down vote.. please.
sorry that i have changed the code to javascript.

Comment: Still do not inline event handlers and do not use the submit button's click handler. Also NEVER call anything in a for `name="submit"` if you plan to execute the submit later. It will overwrite the event handler of the form

Comment: oops.. sorry for that name, i was thinking about value="submit",, but typed in name. really sorry about that

Comment: No problem. I have seen this hundreds of times where people could not understand why they could not submit

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend never to assign validation to a submit button click.
Instead assign the submit event handler of the form.
I also added trim and removed the content of the error from the code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#name').focusout(function() {
    var empty = $.trim($('#name').val()).length == 0;
    $('#adiv').toggle(empty);
  });
  $('#form1').on("submit",function(e) {
    $('#name').focusout();
    if ($('#adiv').is(":visible")) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#adiv { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="register.php" method="post" id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <div id="adiv">please enter name</div><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <div id="adiv"></div>
  <input type="button" value="submit" id="button">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').on('click',function(){

if($('#name').val() == ''){
$('#adiv').text("Please enter name!!");
}else{

    $('#adiv').text($('#name').val());
}

})

})

</script>
```